# Cannot install indicator-netspeed

Tags: apt, updates, dependencies, ppa

When I try to install indicator-netspeed, the system says "The following packages have unmet dependencies". How to resolve it?

The commands that I had used are:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy indicator-netspeed` to the question.

Comment: I did tried copying and pasting the text but askubuntu.com didn't allowed me to do so, saying that "not more than 10 links are allowed" because of less reputations of mine.

Comment: @N0rbert as you likely already know the output of `apt-cache policy indicator-netspeed` is `N: Unable to locate package indicator-netspeed` ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek Yep. But it exists in webupd8 PPA. See your (our :) ) answer below.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for that. I made a minor edit based on yours to improve clarity.

Comment: @AbhigyanGhimire Your question remains unclear - we did not see any error messages. Also note that exists other package `indicator-netspeed-unity` in  [other PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fixnix/+archive/ubuntu/netspeed?field.series_filter=xenial) (you have added it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last check, there was no such package as [`indicator-netspeed` in the repositories.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=indicator-netspeed)

But you can install it from [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=xenial):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed
```

---

An alternative that does exist in the repositories is [indicator-multiload.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=indicator-multiload&searchon=names)

This indicator has the capability of displaying network speeds and much more as shown below.

It looks like this [image] with all the bells and whistles turned on and you can select your output s on the preferences page.

[image: preferences]